# How to set a fixed layout constraint?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am creating a map UI programmatically. I want the top of the view to start after `UINavigationBar` and for the bottom space of 250 from the screen bottom. I have added to the following code:

```
private lazy var mapView: GMSMapView = {
    let mv = GMSMapView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    mv.settings.myLocationButton = true
    mv.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    mv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return mv
}()

override func loadView() {
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height))
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view = v
    updateMap()
    view.addSubview(mapView)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initConstraints()
}

func initConstraints() {
    guard let navVC = navigationController else { return }
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: navVC.navigationBar.frame.maxY),
        mapView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        mapView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -200)  // not working properly
    ])
}
```

Here when setting the bottom anchor, equal space is taken off from top as well, which I don't understand. Please see the attached screenshot.

[image: map view controller]

How to remove the top space, but keep the bottom space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had `mapView.center = view.center` added which was creating this issue. Removing this statement fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.topAnchor,constant:navVC.navigationBar.frame.maxY)
```

**With**

```
mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant:0)
```

**constant:navVC.navigationBar.frame.maxY**

> Means your `UIView` Y Position will be 64 pixels for non-safe area
>   device and 88 pixels for a device with safe area

## Final code:

```
func initConstraints() {
    guard let navVC = navigationController else { return }
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant:0),
        mapView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        mapView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -200)  // not working properly
    ])
}
```